# Problem with keyboard layout after a Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS upgrade

Tags: 20.04, keyboard-layout, language-support

I had no problem with the keyboard languages. Then I performed an upgrade to 22.04.
Everything appeared fine. I even was asked to change the key shortcut to "shift+alt".
But, when I change the keyboard language (either with key shortcut or with the mouse), the language is (supposed to have) changed to Greek, but when I type, the keyboard layout is still English.

I mean, even now that I write, on the bar shows that I have chosen the Greek language.

I checked the keyboard preferences, but there the Greek keyboard appears correct.
Also I used the Onboard app (virtual keyboard on the screen), and when I switch between languages, it doesn't change, and stays English layout.

**Update:**

I do not know *why* it is happening, but I found out *when*. When my laptop is suspended, when I turn it on again, I have the mentioned problem. But when I fully turn off the laptop, then everything works fine (until I suspend it)

Comment: Try doing it twice.

Comment: the second time it changes back to English, and I write in English, as expected. Then again I change it to Greek, but the layout is again English.

Comment: If you have two unused keys (or key combinations), you can set a shortcut each one of them, `setxkbmap us` and `setkbdmap gr`. I do something like this, the benefit of using two keys when I want to change the keyboard layout, doesn't matter which one I am using now, just press the US or GR button!

Comment: The problem is not how to change the layout. It is that every layout "types" english